# iosSlider css setup issue for responsive design

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I downloaded iosSlider demo and trying to modify one of the examples.

iosSlider - https://iosscripts.com/iosslider/
Press big red button to download the demo.

The index.html I'm trying to modify is in iosslider_demos_examples\9-Full-Width-Responsive-Height\3-variable-width\ folder.

Here is the original part of the code before:

```
                <div class = 'slider'>

                    <img src = 'http://placehold.it/400x400/ff00cc/' />
                    <img src = 'http://placehold.it/300x400/ffcc00/' />
                    <img src = 'http://placehold.it/200x400/ccff00/' />
                    <img src = 'http://placehold.it/400x400/cc00ff/' />
                    <img src = 'http://placehold.it/100x400/00ccff/' />
                    <img src = 'http://placehold.it/500x400/00ffcc/' />

                </div>
```

Here is how it looks after I modify it and add DIV elements with a class:

```
                <div class = 'slider'>

                    <div class = 'item'>
                        <img src = 'http://placehold.it/400x500/ff00cc/' />
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'item'>
                        <img src = 'http://placehold.it/300x400/ffcc00/' />
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'item'>
                        <img src = 'http://placehold.it/200x400/ccff00/' />
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'item'>
                        <img src = 'http://placehold.it/400x400/cc00ff/' />
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'item'>
                        <img src = 'http://placehold.it/100x400/00ccff/' />
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'item'>
                        <img src = 'http://placehold.it/500x400/00ffcc/' />
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Once I do that the slider doesn't work properly anymore. I suspect I need to modify CSS for the slider, but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

If you have any ideas let me know. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: please be more clear in your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my post and try to be more specific.

Comment: Updated the post. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

did you start the plug via JS ?
like this exemple :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  /* items_slider */
  $('.slider-marcas .gbtr_items_slider').iosSlider({
   snapToChildren: true,
   desktopClickDrag: true,
   scrollbar: true,
   scrollbarHide: true,
   scrollbarLocation: 'bottom',
   scrollbarHeight: '2px',
   scrollbarBackground: '#ccc',
   scrollbarBorder: '0',
   scrollbarMargin: '0',
   scrollbarOpacity: '1',
   navNextSelector: $('.slider-marcas .gbtr_items_sliders_nav .big_arrow_right'),
   navPrevSelector: $('.slider-marcas .gbtr_items_sliders_nav .big_arrow_left')
  });
 });
```